# Show request line HttpPost

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm trying to send a Post request to a server and it is sending me back data error. I want to check the exact request line I'm sending. Basically I'm doing:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", data1));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data2", data2));
....
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

(here I want to see my request, something like: 
'data1=data1&data2=data2' http://[server.url] )

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You see the response you get? But just want to know what you are sending?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String url = "http://serverurl";
for(int i =0;i<nameValuePairs.size;i++)
{
url = url+"?"+nameValuePairs.get(0).getName()+"="+nameValuePairs.get(0).getValue();
}
Log.v("your url is",url);
```

Comment: @PoweRoy you try to understand the question and then do the downvote. I hadn't asked to execute the get url. the questionnaire wants to see the url and I suggested him the above solution. what's wrong in getting url displayed.

Comment: The URL that is being send is not the one your are displaying. It is not 'http://serverurl?data1=1' but the URL is 'http://serverurl' The data is *in* the request and not in the URL. If the user just wants to see the contents of the post he should loop the array of nameValuePairs.

Comment: @PoweRoy you are right but I thought that questionnaire is unable to trace what the parameters and values he is passing and getting a wrong response. So I just suggested that. Its ok I might understood it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

post.getEntity().getContent().read();
Use this code to read the whole entity you set in HttpPost as request params.
In order to print it to log use this method to convert InputStream to String

```
public static String convertStreamToString (InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append( line + "\n" );
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d( "IOException", "Error occured during convertString " + e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d( "IOException", "Error occured on closing buffer " + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then write Log.d("RequestEntity",convertStreamToString(post.getEntity().getCotent());

Answer (score 0):

Remove your last line: (getEntity) and do this instead:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}

Strong html = builder.toString();
```